# Drawing on JSplitPane not showing

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

Just trying to draw some lines to the screen.

- I've checked to ensure all the relevant code's being run
- I've tried calling repaint (and ensuring that's being run)
- Since this is a JSplitPane, the layout must be the JSplitPane layout
- I'm setting the color to ensure it isn't drawing using the background color.
- I've checked the height and width to ensure its size isn't 0 or something
- I've tried drawing text as well; same result
- I've changed the coordinates all over the place, tried both arbitrary and proportional values

Or at least I think. Swing is unintuitively quirky. I'd use AWT, but I need the specificity Swing offers. Anyway, the code. It's just a split pane, which is actually displaying - resizable and all -  but the contents of the top pane (the only one I've attempted to put anything in) don't show.

```
package derange;

import java.awt.Dimension;


import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;        

public class Derange {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Derange");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Display the window.
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


        //Create a split pane with the two scroll panes in it.
        PanelScore scorePane = new PanelScore();
        JScrollPane instrumentPane = new JScrollPane();
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                                   scorePane, instrumentPane);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation((frame.getHeight() / 4) * 3 );// Three-quarters of the way down
        splitPane.setDividerSize(20);

        //Provide minimum sizes for the two components in the split pane
        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()/ 2);//width, height
        scorePane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize); //Score takes up at least half the screen
        instrumentPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));//no minimum size on the instrument panel; collapsible

        frame.getContentPane().add(splitPane);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

.

```
package derange;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")//wtf is this needed for?

public class PanelScore extends JScrollPane{

    public int strings = 6;

    public void drawStaffTablature(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);

        int xStart = 30;//insets.left;
        int xEnd = getParent().getWidth() - 30;
        int yCoord = this.getHeight() / 2;
        System.out.println(this.isShowing());

        //Space between tablature lines
        int lineSpacing = 15;
        //Space between staffs.
        int staffSpacing = 60;`enter code here`
        for(int x = 0; x < strings; x++){
            g2d.drawLine(xStart, yCoord + (lineSpacing * x), xEnd, yCoord + (lineSpacing * x));
            //System.out.println("String: " + (x + 1));
             g.drawString("Test", xStart, yCoord); //change the co-odrinates
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawStaffTablature(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: Painting should never reference outside components, this `int xEnd = getParent().getWidth() - 30;` is a bad idea

Comment: Don't extend from `JScrollPane`, short answer is, it has `JViewport` which covers it's "viewable" are, which you are actually painting under

Comment: This is not relevant to the question, but here is what you helped me create: http://imgur.com/kkLuLkx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, don't extend from `JScrollPane`, a `JScrollPane` contains single component known as a `JViewport`, which covers the most of the scroll pane (the rest is taken up by the `JScrollBar`s

[image]

Instead, try extending from something like `JPanel`.

I'd also advise you against using anything like `int xEnd = getParent().getWidth() - 30;` within your paint code, the `Graphics` context is translated to the components location, making the top/left corner `0x0` and clipped to the components current width and height

Comment: The getParent().getWidth() thing was just me grasping at straws hoping to stumble into a solution. 

Your solution worked! I inherited from JPanel instead, drew to that, and added it to the JScrollPanel's viewport.